# VBA script to to get URLs status code

Tags: vba

So, I have this Excel macro-enabled sheet with a list of about 500 URLs. (All pages on our corporate intranet.)

Now we want to check how many URLs are working fine with the use of URL status code

.

However, there is some good news: The redirect script does not run from within Excel. If you click a bad link inside Excel, the redirect script does not execute and the HTTP response is reported back to Excel. I believe Excel should be able to identify the correct HTTP response code (404) - or at least whether the link was valid or not.

Which brings me to my question:

I have passed the Winhttp request object to send HTTP POST request and applied a request.status method to a getting status of the URLs.

I have got the correct output but I found some of the URLs are working fine but it shows the 404 status in the macro.

Ex:http://www.xroadscap.com

If anyone if familiar enough with VBA to suggest a solution to this problem, I would be eternally grateful!

Here is my VBA Script.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim source As Range, req As Object, url$

Dim rc As Integer

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select

  Set source = Range("A1:A1000")
  source.Columns(2).Clear

For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count

    url = source.Cells(i, 1)


    On Error Resume Next

    req.Open "HEAD", url, False

   req.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"

    req.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"

    req.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"

    req.SetRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"

    req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

    req.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"

 req.Send

source.Cells(i, 2) = req.Status





On Error GoTo 0
  Next




  MsgBox "Finished!"
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need all those headers, and what happens if you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem statement? This in particular is not clear: *I have got the correct output but I found some of the URLs are working fine but it shows the 404 status in the macro.*.

Comment: any particular reason behind using `ServerXMLHTTP`?